# Appropriate Place To Ask For Reviews/Criticisms on Campaign Log / GM Skills?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions

Is this stackExchange site an appropriate place to ask for performance criticisms and reviews?   For example, if I have a campaign log for a recently concluded campaign, can/should I post a link to it and ask people what they would have handled differently, how they would have approached certain problems differently, or ways that they feel I (the GM, in this case) mis-managed the campaign?

Comment: Good idea.  Question title edited for clarification.

Comment: Thanks! [ ](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/566/8)

Comment: FYI @brianballsunstanton opened up a [chat](http://chat.rpg.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/campaign-discussion) called "campaign discussion". There are links to at least two other campaigns so far. You should join in!

Answer (score 7):

I think that's too general - if you can scope it down to a specific element, then it might make a good question though.  Not "Here's my session summary what did I do wrong," but "How do you handle players getting frustrated by puzzles?  Let me illustrate with the events of a recent session of mine...."

Bits of actual play from real campaigns are EXTREMELY DESIRABLE both in questions and answers - in an answer, I consider those about 1000% more helpful than people spouting off their opinion of how things *might* be.  I vote up Q's and A's with examples from real life unstintingly.  So posting a whole summary for general critique is too vague and unfocused, but I encourage you to do the same in a more targeted way.

Answer (score 5):

My sense is no, posting an entire campaign log as a single question is outside the scope of the site because that would be a very large, complex discussion with multiple facets and interpretations. A forum, message board, or email conversation is probably a better avenue. (You could definitely ask a question about where to find such a place online.)

Two other options I can think of:

- Read through your notes and break it down into a series of specific questions and ask those! If one relies on another, you can include a link to other questions in your questions. As mxyzplk [says](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/566/appropriate-place-to-ask-for-reviews-criticisms-on-campaign-log-gm-skills/569#569), please *do* include details from you notes! It makes them more interesting and adds the context that makes for good questions.
- You could ask for or create a room/table on the chat page specifically on the topic of discussing your campaign notes. (I think you need 100 rep to create your own.) I am not sure how you would recruit people to it or get them to 'stop by' but that seems like a possible use of the chat rooms.

**Update:**

[General campaign discussion chat room](http://chat.rpg.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/campaign-discussion) has been created.

Comment: I made a chat room for discussion, as it feels like the right place for that kind of informal, personal, reflection. We'll see if it's used.